# What is $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: limits

What is the limit of $\frac{(-1)^n}{ n}$ as $n$ approaches positive infinity?

I can see how it would converge to zero, as the denominator swiftly over powers the numerator. However, the top goes into the imaginary plane for non-integer $n$. Furthermore, since the limit as $x$ goes toward infinity of $\sin(x)$ is DNE, would the same logic apply here?

Is the answer $0$ or DNE?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes it is, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment because, reading more carefully, you actually referred to non-integer values of $n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow 0 
$$

Answer (score 3):

What matters,
even if we consider
real $n$ instead of
integer $n$,
is that
$|(-1)^n|
=|e^{\pi i n}|
=|\cos(\pi n)+i\sin(\pi n)|
=1
$.

Therefore,
as Hamza wrote,
$|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}|
=|\frac{1}{n}|
\to 0
$
as
$n \to \infty$
for real or integer $n$.